# C# this.Equals(typeof(...));

Tags: c#, this, typeof, equals-operator

I have following piece of code:

```
class Tile
{
    public TCODColor color { get; protected set; }
    public int glyph { get; protected set; }

    public Boolean isDigable()
    {
        return this.Equals(typeof(Wall));
    }
    public Boolean isGround()
    {
        return this.Equals(typeof(Floor));
    }
}
```

The Wall and Floor class both inherit from Tile. At another point in the program I have a if-statement which goes like this for example:

```
public void dig(int x, int y)
{
    if (tiles[x, y].isDigable())
    {
        tiles[x,y] = new Floor();
    }
}
```

The tiles are a two-dimensional array of the Tile class and the content of them gets initialized either as a Floor or Wall. So if the tile is a Wall it is Digable (and should return true) but no matter what it always returns false, thus, not executing other code. Since I am not familiar with C# I suppose I am doing something wrong Syntax-wise, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is for testing if two values are equivalent (in some way), for example, to test if two variables of type `Floor` refer to the same instance in memory.

To test if an object is of a certain type, use the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
public Boolean isDigable()
{
    return this is Wall;
}

public Boolean isGround()
{
    return this is Floor;
}
```

Or as *Rotem* suggests, you can modify your classes to make `isDigable` and `isGround` [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) methods and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) them in your child classes, like this:

```
class Tile
{
    public TCODColor color { get; protected set; }
    public int glyph { get; protected set; }

    public virtual bool isDigable() 
    { 
        return false; 
    }

    public virtual bool isGround() 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}

class Wall: Tile
{
    public override bool isDigable()
    { 
        return true; 
    }
}

class Floor : Tile
{
    public override bool isGround()
    { 
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The sane way is to make `isDigable` and `isGround` virtual and have `Wall` and `Floor` override them. As it is written, `Tile` must know about all its subclasses.

Comment: Perfect, worked, thanks! @Rotem I know but I have reasons to do it like this.

Comment: @Rotem Good suggestion. I've included such a solution for completeness.

Comment: If you're going the virtual route, you might as well make them properties as well.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Yeah I started writing them as properties, but then I decided I didn't want to change *too much* of OP's code. I just wanted to highlight polymorphism.